# OMAP: Building and installing ltrace

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, omap

Anyone know where I can find instructions for cross compiling [ltrace](http://ltrace.alioth.debian.org/) for the OMAP processor? I downloaded **ltrace_0.5.3.orig.tar.gz** from [here](ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/ltrace/), and tried cross compiling by passing the approriate parameters to the configure script, but I does not appear to support anything but plain old gcc.

According to the documentation it supports ARM. Maybe I need to pull the package from somewhere else?

Comment: I am trying to cross compile ltrace for ARM architecture. Can you kindly post the relevant instructions for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ltrace_0.5.3 configure is not a script generated by autoconf, so standard --build option doesn't do anything.
To specify which compiler to use you need to do give CC option, e.g:
./configure CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Also take care that:
- CPPFLAGS is set to ' -I /usr/include/libelf'
- ltrace requires libelf
- check in configure are made with gcc